# String comparison and String interning in Java

Tags: java, string, equals, string-comparison, string-interning

When should one compare `String`s as objects and when should one use their `equals` method? To make sure, I always use `equals`, but that doesn't seem very efficient. In what situations can I be certain that `string1 == string2` is a safe to use?

Comment: String.equals() is efficient. The first thing checked is if string1 == string2. (Actually Object.equals() checks this.)

Comment: But of course! How *stupid* of me. It's a very obvious thing to do. And highly efficient one as you say. Never though of it. *Shame on me!* Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should almost *always* use `equals`. You can be certain that `string1 == string2` will work if:

- You've already made sure you've got distinct values in some other way (e.g. you're using string values fetched from a set, but comparing them for some other reason)
- You know you're dealing with compile-time string constants
- You've manually interned the strings yourself

It really doesn't happen very often, in my experience.

Comment: Absolutely the right answer. Using '==' because equals() is inefficient is a great example of premature optimization.

Comment: And String.intern() is slow enough to be useless for performance in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know of Java, `string1==string2` will only be true if the references to those objects are the same. Take a look at the following case

```
String string1 = new String("Bob");
String string2 = new String("Bob");

string1 == string2; // false, they are seperate objects
string1 = string2;  // asigning string1 to string2 object
string1 == string2; // true, they both refer to the same object
```

Comment: The first comparison will *not* be false because they are *not* separate objects. String literals are interned in Java.

Comment: The first comparison should return false in this case-
String string1 = new("Bob");
String string2 = new("Bob");

Comment: I'll edit my responce to make it more clearly defined. I thought I might run into this issue with Java.

Comment: @stratwine: No, this is not true. See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.5: Each string literal is a reference (§4.3) to an instance (§4.3.1, §12.5) of class String (§4.3.3). String objects have a constant value. String literals-or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28)-are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

Comment: The answer is correct, and the first comparison is 'false'. "new String(...)" creates (surprise surprise) a new String, which is not the same object as the interned "Bob".

Comment: @Dirk - Strings created at compile time are interned. Not the Strings that are created on the fly. new operator creates the String at runtime and there's no interning involved here.

Comment: @stratwine: Seems I misread your comment. I thought that you'd tried to "expand" the poster's original formulation of the initial assignments instead of providing an alternative case to elaborate on. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the `==` for comparison if you are sure the objects are the same.

For example, this could occur if you had a final static String variable. You could be certain that a comparison would be between the same object.

Stick with the `equals` for string comparison.