# Basic addition and subtraction with choices

Tags: java, class, jcreator

Please help with this. I am very new to this, and I need this badly. I need to create a program where it lets you choose from addition or subtraction. This is my current program:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RationalZ {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "Enter the letter A for Addition and B Subtraction");

        String choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            "A=Addition B=Subtraction");

        if (choice == "a") {

            String strNum1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "Enter a Number");
            String strNum2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "Enter a second number");

            int aNum1 = Integer.parseInt(strNum1);
            int aNum2 = Integer.parseInt(strNum2);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, aNum1 + aNum2);

            System.exit(0);

        } else {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong? Even in the first step I can't get it.

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: please be specific and explain what your problem is.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to review the difference between the `==` operator and the `equals()` method.

Addendum: It's fairly easy to find good information on Java [`String`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) [comparison methods](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html); it's a little harder to find a [good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885753/string-comparison-and-string-interning-in-java) of why `==` with `String` is usually wrong.

Addendum:

> Do I use another if statement?

You've got a good [`if-then`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) statement; now you need to expand it to an [if-then-else](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) statement. Notice how you can add more [`if-then`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) statements after the `else`.

Comment: my problem is that im stuck and i dont know what to do anymore T.T

Comment: @Richard: I've added two links above that may help. Don't hesitate to ask additional questions.

Comment: i placed this if (choice equals(a)) { but i get errors uhmm what would be the correct way? of using the equals()?

Comment: @Richard: You're almost there; `equals()` is a _method_, so you'd use the `choice.equals("a")` syntax. Notice how `"a".equals(choice)` is a nearly equivalent test. Now, what if the user types "A"? Do you see a method for that?

Comment: omg thanks so much ^__^ it worked! im gonna continue on now ^_^ thanks alot^_^ ill be postin if i get into trouble again! thanks man ^_^

Comment: uhm now im stuck again, i we got it to work... but now i dont know how to let the person to choose b for subtraction... do i use another if statement? and if yes, where?

Comment: `if(condition1){ //code for sum } else if (condition2) { //code for subtraction } else { //everything else }`

Comment: nvm i figured it already bro ^_^ thanks neway.. now all i need is to make my users choice pretty

Comment: any suggestions on how to make them choose a or b? or how do you make them so that they see a box and tick a or b then press ok?

Comment: @Richard: You can put any components you need in a panel as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002830