# java if statement error

Tags: java, android, view, if-statement

It seems to me that this `if` statement is not working.

I'm new in java, but i know C# and C++ pretty well, but I've never seen such a thing before:

```
today=edit[0].substring(0,10);
if (today == edit[0].substring(0,10))
{
    pars_prog.addView(name_prog[i]);
}
```

And it doesn't get into the `IF` function?

Are if statements different in Java (Android)?

Comment: I don't thing this gets to your question but nonetheless it is bad practice to use the == operator there.  Better if ( today . equals ( edit[0].substring(0,10) )

Comment: It's not the `if` that works differently, it's the String object (and therefore the `==`). As the answers suggest: use `.equals()`

Comment: from ur coding i ll u r best coder in this universe..

Comment: possible duplicate of [String comparison and String interning in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885753/string-comparison-and-string-interning-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `==` for *any* object references (whether strings or any other non-primitive type) it simply compares whether the references are equal - i.e. whether they refer to the exact same object, or whether they're both null.

In this case, you want to determine whether the strings are *equal* - i.e. whether they represent the same sequence of characters. You should use the `equals` method for that:

```
if (today.equals(edit[0].substring(0,10)))
```

However, in general when doing this you should be careful that the target of the `equals` call is non-null, or you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

Note that C# is *similar* - except that the `==` operator can be overloaded, and *is* overloaded for `string`. If the compile-time types of the operands aren't both `string`, you'll still get reference comparison:

```
object text1 = new StringBuilder("hello").ToString();
object text2 = new StringBuilder("hello").ToString();
Console.WriteLine(text1 == text2); // False
```

Comment: Thank you mate, this is exactly what i've been looking for

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to compare strings with `==`, which is identity comparison - it will check if the two are the same instance (in the JVM) rather than comparing their contents.

Use `today.equals(..)` instead.

That said, if appears you are working with dates, so a `String` is not the best way to handle this. Use `Calendar`, `Date` (a bit obsolete) or joda-time `DateTime`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the equals method when comparing strings.. Right now you are comparing references and thats why you never enter the if block